# Use a slider to set the time of an AudioSource in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, user-interface, audio

I need to use a Unity slider to change the time of an AudioSource. As now the slider is capable to display the time position the AudioSource is on, but I also need it to edit the position. Here's my code:

```
public Slider time;
public AudioSource audio;
// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    audio = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    time.maxValue = audio.clip.length;
    time.value = audio.time;
    audio.time = time.value;
}
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public Slider slider;
private AudioSource audioS;

private void Awake()
{
    audioS = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
}

void Update()
{
    slider.maxValue = audioS.clip.length;
}

public void OnSliderValueChanged()
{
    audioS.time = slider.value;
}

private void FixedUpdate()
{
    slider.value = audioS.time;
}
```

Once you have this code in your file, simply **go to your slider**. All the way **down in the properties** panel, you will find **"OnValueChanged"** **put** your object with your **script** attached to it and simply **choose your function**. Your function will now be called everytime you change the value of the slider.

Comment: I'm gonna try. I'll keep you updated

Comment: No problem :) don't forget to accept the answer as correct i need points so i can comment on posts rather than using only answers x) Have a nice day !